# How can I start a process when this play symbol comes up

Tags: ios, audio, label, streaming, playback

In my app I am streaming audio and there is a period of 5-10 sec depending on the connection where the buffer is loading and after this, my app starts to play the audio. When it starts to play the audio this symbol comes up in the screen.

Here is an image of what im talking about.

http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/3667/img0596.png

I want to change a label in my app when this symbol comes up in the screen, but i dont know which function let me detect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol is the "Play" button common to music devices. There is most likely an NSNotification center message that can be "listened for". However, depending on how you are buffering your sounds there is probably a delegate that can notify a selector once it has begun playback. Without more details I can not give more detailed advice. If I were in your position I would take a very hard look at the API you are utilizing, most likely several methods exist to either post notification or send delegate messages notifying the state of the stream as well as playback. I have worked with some streaming audio API and I was able to get status of the buffer as well many other messages from the stream object(s). These are just part of good design, so most likely it is there.

Comment: Im using the MPMoviePlayer to do my stream, and there is a way to access the playback state of the player. Specifically im using this methods -(void)changeStatus
{   

    if (player.loadState == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        status.text = @"Buffering...";
    }
    if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
        {
            status.text = @"Playing.";
        }
   if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
        {
            status.text = @"Paused";
        }

} but this doesnt seem to work, because it changes my label to playing before the buffer loads.

Comment: Ok, so you should be good to go to change your view. Good luck and I hope my response helped!

Comment: in the MPMoviePlayerController protocol, there should be a method for preparing to play or something to that effect, overriding it should allow you to fire the buffering message.

Comment: Im almost getting to the solution the only problem is that i cant show the buffering label. It just jumps immediately to the playing label. And thats wrong because it shows "Playing " but actually it isnt playing anything yet, its charging the buffer.

Comment: I tried it now. Overriding the prepare to play, didnt work it shows the buffering label for half a sec and immediately changes the status to "Playing". I dont know if there is a method to know when the buffer finish loading, because when it finishes loading it immediately shows the play icon i was talking about.

Comment: I did a quick look at my notes on MP player Notifications seem to be the easiest way to go. Register for MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification in the enumeration returned from the notification "MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted" is the indicator that the buffer is charging. You could also get all of the states from this message and adjust your display accordingly, if you wanted.

Comment: I achieved it! I really thank you a lot. However, i didnt use the MPMoviePlayerLoadstateDidChangeNotification. In my play method I restored the [player prepareToPlay] method i overrided but after that instead of just put [player play] I placed an if clause if(player.isPreparedToPlay){[player play]} You were right the "MPMOviePlaybackState" refers to the buffering state so in my "changeStatus" method I also added that part. And that made the difference. Again I really appreciated your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that I could help, having headaches over my current project so its nice to sometimes just crawl around on these forums to get the creative juices flowing. Best of luck with your app